# Unable to see reason for HHVM restart failure

Tags: php, hhvm

My `/etc/hhvm/php.ini` currently looks like this:

```
display_startup_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On

hhvm.error_handling.call_user_handler_on_fatals = 1
hhvm.server.implicit_flush = 1
```

The first 3 directives cause `sudo service hhvm restart` to fail.  If I remove those 3 directives it restarts ok.  When the service fails to restart I do not see any reason for the failure inside of `/var/log/hhvm/error.log`.

Am I looking at the correct log file?
Should php.ini configuration not go in this file?

My reason for adding these ini directives is to see fatal errors output in my php application.  Any advice you can offer would be very helpful.

```
$ hhvm --version
HipHop VM 3.6.5 (rel)
Compiler: tags/HHVM-3.6.5-0-g20a30678cd67fad96602ffd93e69780d001ce57f
Repo schema: 53a4026d3732c3584cffef19fa47fea655be3c4f
```

Answer (score 2):

`On` and `E_ALL` appear to not be understood by HHVM.  This works:

```
display_startup_errors = 1
error_reporting = 8191
display_errors = 1
```